# How to resolve assert WINRT_ASSERT(!is_sta()) in winrt::impl::blocking_suspend

Tags: c++-winrt

I have a Win32 DLL I am trying to convert to be usable from UWP. I need to replace file handling code (CreateFile, ReadFile, etc.) to the WinRT safe equivalents (Windows::Storage::StorageFile). I have the code converted and compiling, but when I run the app I get this exception calling get on the returned async operations and I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: You are attempting to synchronously wait for an async operation on the GUI thread. Without seeing a [mcve], it's hard to contrive a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, took a bit to figure out what I was doing wrong but the correct way to handle this in my case is to wrap my code in a co_routine and then call it using PPL.

```cpp
IAsyncOperation<int> DoWork()
{
    co_await winrt::resume_background();
    …
    return someValue;
}

int Foo()
{
   return create_task([]{
       return DoWork().get();
   }).get();
}
```

Comment: While this silences the C++/WinRT diagnostic, it still exhibits the same issue the diagnostic was warning you about: Synchronously waiting on the GUI thread. This is not something you should be doing in general. It may solve your immediate issue, but it's hard to tell, *what* your issue is, given that your question is still fairly incomplete.

Comment: Right, the assertion is a reminder not to block the UI thread. You can for example call your DoWork coroutine from the UI thread, but you must not block and wait for its completion on the UI thread. You can instead use the coroutine itself to wait for completion.

Comment: I am running into the same problem trying to get the BluetoothAdapter. Also in a dll. Is there a way to access the default bluetooth adapter without blocking? In a callback perhaps?